# Is this result on the set of differentiability of the distance function to the fat Cantor set of any interest?

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, geometric-measure-theory, fractals

**Quick summary:**

Consider the [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) $C$ of parameter $r$ for arbitrary $0 < r < \frac{1}{3}$, and the distance function to $C$, i.e. $D: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ given by $D(x) =\text{dist}(x, C)$.

The distance function is Lipschitz continuous, hence by [Rademacher’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem), differentiable almost everywhere. In particular, since $C$ has nonzero measure, it is differentiable at some points in $C$. I believe I have a characterization of the set on which it is differentiable. For those interested in the precise result, the details are given below.

From a quick search I have not been able to find much on this topic. Has this result been proven before, or have similar problems been studied?

As an aside, I wonder there is any nice extension to the nonhomogeneous case, where a proportion $r_n$ is removed at the $n$'th stage.

Thanks in advance! Also I did not state some definitions in full, so feel free to ask for any clarification!

**Detailed version:**

Let $C \subset [0, 1]$ be a fat Cantor set, for parameter $0 < r < 1/3$. Thus intervals of width $r^n$ are removed from the middle of the previous intervals at each step. For the given range of $r$ this produces a fat Cantor set, i.e. the measure of $C$ is nonzero.

Write $C = \cap C_n$ for the usual decomposition of $C$, so that $C_n$ represents the leftover set after the $n$'th iteration, and define the address function $A: C \to [0, 1]$ by the following -

$A(1) = 1, A(0) = 0$, and for $x \in C \cap (0, 1)$, the $k$'th binary decimal digit, $b_k A(x)$ of $A(x)$ is defined by the following:

$b_1 (x) = 0$ if $x$ lies to the left of the deleted interval in stage $1$, and $1$ otherwise.

For general $k$, $b_k A(x) = 0$ if $x$ lies to the left of the interval deleted from the connected component of $x$ in $C_{k-1}$ at stage $k$ and $1$ otherwise.

For each $x \in C$, define $$L_x (k) := \sup \{{ j \in \mathbb Z^+ |\; b_{h+k-1} A(x) = b_k A(x) \;\textrm{for all}\; h \in  \mathbb Z^+ \; \textrm{with} \; h \leq j\}}$$

so that $L_x (k)$ is the length of the longest consecutive string of $0's$ or $1's$ beginning at the $k$'th decimal point of the address of $x$. By convention we shall always choose the binary expansion that ends in an infinite string of $1$’s when possible.

Fix $0 < r < \frac{1}{3}$, and consider the function $D: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ defined by $D(x) := \text{dist}(x, C)$, where $D$ denotes the Euclidean distance from a point to a set.

Then $D$ is Lipschitz continuous (with Lipschitz constant $1$), so is differentiable a.e. by Rademacher's theorem. Outside $C$, it is easily verified that $D$ is differentiable everywhere except the midpoints of the removed intervals. For the points in $C$, we have

> **Theorem:** There exists a constant $M > 0$, depending only on $r$ such that $D$ is differentiable at $x \in C$ if and only if $\lim_{k \to \infty} k - ML_x (k) = \infty$.

*Remark:* There is also an explicit expression for $M$ in terms of $r$.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, the function $f$ only appears once in your theorem statement.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $D$ of course.

Comment: The middle-$r$ Cantor set is not what is known as a "fat Cantor set".  A fat Cantor set has positive Lebesgue measure, whereas the middle-$r$ Cantor set has measure $0$.

Comment: Right, I mean the one with positive measure, so maybe I should change the terminology. The set I describe with r = 1/4 I think is known as the Smith Volterra Cantor set - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set.

Comment: To get a "fat" Cantor set, you need $r_n \to 0$ fast enough.